# NextJS revalidate doesn't work with standalone server

Tags: docker, next.js

It looks like the revalidation option doesn't work when using the standalone server of NextJS.

I got this:

```js
    return {
      props: {
        page,
      },
      revalidate: 60,
    };
```

I have the following NextJS config:

```js
    {
      output: "standalone",
      reactStrictMode: true,
      swcMinify: true,
      i18n: {
        locales: ["default", "en", "nl", "fr"],
        defaultLocale: "default",
        localeDetection: false,
      },
      trailingSlash: true,
    }
```

And I use the following docker file to create a container:

```bash
    # Install dependencies only when needed
    FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
    # Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
    RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
    WORKDIR /app
    
    # Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
    COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
    RUN \
      if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
      elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
      elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
      else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
      fi
    
    
    # Rebuild the source code only when needed
    FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
    COPY . .
    
    # Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
    # Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
    # Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
    # ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
    
    RUN yarn build
    
    # If using npm comment out above and use below instead
    # RUN npm run build
    
    # Production image, copy all the files and run next
    FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
    WORKDIR /app
    
    ENV NODE_ENV production
    # Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
    # ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
    
    RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
    RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs
    
    COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
    
    # Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
    # https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
    COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
    COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static
    
    USER nextjs
    
    EXPOSE 3000
    
    ENV PORT 3000
    
    CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Tried many things myself but nothing works and on the internet I keep coming across that you have to run on a NextJS server, but if I'm correct, that is what you do when running it standalone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got into the issue more and found some more errors. Found out that the next/image component's default loader uses squoosh because it is quick to install and suitable for a development environment. But for a production environment using output: "standalone", you must install sharp.

So I runned

```
yarn add sharp
```

And that error was not happening anymore. But still I didn't get an update on my content. Because I could not get this working and I need to continue with the project I checked out On-Demand revalidation. Read more about it here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration

So what I now did was:

1. create an API end-point in my NextJS solution to revalidate.
2. use the webhook from my CMS to call that api end-point

That did the trick for me. I could now just update something in my CMS, the webhook was triggered and then I got a new fresh build page with the changes!

In my eyes this is a beter solution because:

- It only revalidate the page when it is really needed
- After the change/revalidation the next visitor directly see's the new updated version

So i'm happy that it didn't worked and with an bit of extra efford I got a way better solution!

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: I implemented this solution - using webhook to on-demand revalidate - but the server still serves the stale version.

Comment: @BeshoyTamry I had to debug my end-point to make sure I've used the correct and full path when I did res.revalidate() call. Including the locale that I wanted to revalidate. Starting with a /.
So in my case I needed to do:
res.revalidate('/en/blog/test-article');
and not only the slug ('test-article') that the CMS was given.

Hopes it helps you!

Comment: @BeshoyTamry Hi, How you solve this issue?